# Convert Decimal Number to Boolean Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In Python 3.8 I want to take an integer (always between 0 and 8) and convert that to an array with a boolean representation for each binary digit. I've come up with something but it feels to be a rather round about way to get what I want:

```
import numpy as np

curInput = 5
myArray = np.array(list(map(int, list(f"{curInput:08b}"))),dtype='bool').tolist()
```

The above creates `[False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True]` which is what I need (I needs the array to always be a size of 8) but it certainly feels over complicated.

Comment: `[bit == "1" for bit in f"{curInput:08b}"]`? A round trip through a numpy array is not necessary to get a boolean.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it without converting to string and back (or using numpy): `[bool(curInput & (1 << i)) for i in range(7, -1, -1)]`

Comment: @zvone the string comes out much faster in `timeit`

Comment: The problem is you `map` to an `int`. Just `map` directly to a boolean. `list(map(lambda x: x == "1", f"{curInput:08b}"))`, which is identical to jon's list comp. The extra cast of the f-string to list is also not necessary -- duck typing FTW!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was actually wondering whether that might be true. Thanks for sharing that info :)

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, that does like a better solution without having to use numpy

Answer (score 3):

One time create an array

```
bits = np.array([128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1])
```

After that

```
(bits & value) != 0
```

will give you the array you need for any value.

Comment: `bits = (1 << np.arange(8))[::-1]`, so you don't have to type those yourself ;)

Comment: @zvone Yeah.  It was faster to just type the integers than to make sure I got all the parentheses correct.  It original poster wanted 16 bits, I would have done that.